# What is $\int_{0}^1 x^{- m x} dx$ when $m$ is large?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

I am looking for an estimate to the following definite integral:
$$I(m) = \int_{0}^1 x^{-m x} dx$$
as a function of $m$, asymptotically when $m$ is large.

I found out that the maximum value of the integrand is attained when $x=1/e$, and it is $M(m) := exp({m\over e})$.  So $J(m) := I(m) / M(m)$ is finite. Moreover, by [plotting the integrand](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kgpziriyga) of $J(m)$ it seems that $J(m) \to 0$ as $m\to \infty$, so:
$$
I(m) \in o\left(exp({m\over e})\right)
$$
What is a more accurate estimate of $I(m)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a laplace method integral. You can write the integrand as $e^{-mg(x)}$ for $g(x)=x\log x.$ Then you Taylor expand $g(x)$ about its local minimum at $x=1/e$ as $$g(x)\approx -1/e +\frac{e}{2}(x-1/e)^2.$$ Finally changing the limits of the integral to $\pm\infty$ only introduces exponential error terms. So you have a Gaussian integral to do and you get $$ I(m) = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi }{em}} e^{m/e}(1+ O(1/\sqrt m))$$

Comment: I wouldn't call the real-variable Laplace method "steepest descent" (which I would think of as a complex-variable generalization).

Comment: @Ian k, changed it

Comment: The Laplace method is all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)= x^{-x}/e^{1/e}.$ Then $f$ has a strict local maximum of $1$ at $1/e.$ Your quotient $I(m)/J(m)$ is exactly

$$\tag 1 \int_0^1 f(x)^m\, dx.$$

Since $0<f(x)<1$ on $[0,1]\setminus \{1/e\},$ we can see immediately that $(1)\to 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

For asymptotics, I know from Laplace's method that $(1)$ is on the order of $1/\sqrt m.$ Check out Laplace's method for more information.